# How can I compare a value of time with a time slot?

Tags: c, list, singly-linked-list, timeslots

I am reading from a file (fp) fourplets, that represent packets and if the generation time of the packet is less than the time running, then I am inserting it in to my list. The time increases by 20.0 every time slot. But I want to check all the packets from the file for the time between 0 and 20 and then between 20 and 40 etc. For example if a packet has generation time 13.9 and the time slot is 0-20, that means the packet will be inserted in the list, but another packet with generation time 24.5 will not be inserted in the list. I wrote the code below but it does not work like that.

```
  double time=0.0;  
  while( fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),fp) != NULL ){
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %lf",&rollnumber, &src, &dest, &gentime);
    printf("time: %.1f\n",time);
    while (gentime<time && insertedpackets<=10){ 
            insert(rollnumber,src,dest,gentime);
            insertedpackets++;
            display();
        }time=time+20.0;
```

Comment: Show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I mean, if a packet has generation time=16.5, it will be inserted in the list because the time slot will be 0-20. On the other hand if a packet has generation time=23 it will not be inserted in the list for the same time slot. But I want to check all the packets from the file until the last one for the same time slot.

Comment: You still have to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can play with. Of course we need also some sample data to test with.

Comment: From your description, it seems like you would just want to compute `floor(gentime/20.0)` to figure out which time slot a given entry belongs to and then just insert it into that slot's list?

Comment: @Chris Dodd could you explain this more? It’s a bit confusing